# How to pass several props in spread operator in react

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
let objA = {varA,varB};
let objB = {varC, varD};
```

I'd like to pass varA,varB,varC,varD to my component, but not one by one because the number of variables inside objA and objB should be unknown.

I've read in react docs that this is possible with spread operator:

```
let bothObjects = {...arrA, ...arrB};
<Component {...bothObjects} />
```

But is it possible to do without the third object?

This works:

```
<Component {...objA} {...objB} />
```

But I'm not sure it's correct...
This also works:

```
<Component {...{...objA,...objB}} />
```

But it looks funny and I don't fully understand this.

This, however, **does not work**:

```
<Component {...objA, ...objB} />
```

and I'm not sure why... because it worked when I initialized 'bothObjects' above... It also looks to my like the proper way to do it intuitively.

Where am I mistaking?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rest parameters should be the [last named argument of a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), you're passing two. You should divide both into separate `props`, like in your working example:

```
<Component {...objA} {...objB} />
```

In this example you have two `props`, the with Rest parameter is the first one.

```
function sum(...theArgs, q) {
 return theArgs.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous + current;
  });
}`
```

When I put the `q` parameter it gives me the error:

> Error: parameter after rest parameter

EDIT: And @Omar is right, in this case there's no need for using Rest Parameters, since both are simple objects

Answer (score 87):

First a look in JSX. When you do (**scenario 1**):

```html
<Component myProp={something} />
```

The `something` typically is a JavaScript expression.

When you use the spread operator, like (**scenario 2**):

```html
<Component {...something} />
```

Then `something` should be a **JavaScript object**.

## Your case

Considering `objA` and `objB` are two JavaScript objects, you can use them like *scenario 2* above:

```html
<Component {...objA} {...objB} />
```

And they should **work** as expected.

When you do:

```html
let bothObjects = {...objA, ...arrB};
<Component {...bothObjects} />
```

Again, it **works** because `bothObjects` is too an object. Just one object that happens to have been built based on `objA` and `objB`.

The other case:

```html
<Component {...{...objA,...objB}} />
```

May seem weird, but **works** perfectly. See, from *scenario 2* above, JSX expects (in `{...something}`) that `something` is an object. And `{...objA,...objB}` ***is*** an object. Well, it's actually an expression that "returns" a value of object type, but it's the same. It works fine.

The last case:

```html
<Component {...objA, ...objB} />
```

Does **not** work because the expresion `objA, ...objB` is not a JavaScript object. It actually means nothing, it is a syntax error. See the error message:

```
VM2296 babel.js:17994 Uncaught SyntaxError: Babel script: Unexpected token, expected }
  30 | 
  31 |       <Bob
> 32 |         {...objA, ...objB}
     |                 ^
```

As you can see, after the char `A` of `...objA`, JSX just expected to find the `}`. But it found a `,` which is an error (*Unexpected token*).

## What to use?

Considering all three forms that work:

```html
let bothObjects = {...objA, ...arrB};
<Component {...bothObjects} />
<Component {...objA} {...objB} />
<Component {...{...objA,...objB}} />
```

To say which one is better is just a matter of taste. Pick whatever *you* think is more readable.

Comment: What about when this works ` { ...{ attributes } }` but this doesn;t ` { ...attributes }`. React can be pretty weird, man.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the following

`let objA = {varA,varB};`
`let objB = {varC, varD};`

To pass these as props you simply do

`<Component objA={objA} objB={objB} />`

Theres no reason to use `...` syntax.

Simply acess them in the component with `this.props.objA` or `this.props.objB`. You can then do whatever you want with these objects in the respective component you passed it down to.

Answer (score 1):

This was my use case. Changing some props from a defined object:

```
<Component someProp={{...{...someObject, ...{someValue: false}}}} />
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass it with extra braces like below -

where this.closeModal is my method in react class component.

`{...{ ...this.props, closeModal: this.closeModal }}`

Passing more props:

```
{...{ ...
    this.props,
    method1: param => this.method1(param),
    method2: _ => this.method2()
}}
```